# ASP.NET MVC User.Identity.GetUserId() returning wrong GUID

Tags: membership-provider, asp.net-mvc-5

I am calling this method from within a Controller method while logged in as a user, with the standard DefaultMembershipProvider code in MVC5 that comes completely out of the box. Like this:

```
 string LoggedInUsersId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

When debugging, this method call returns a GUID that is completely different to the "Id" field GUID stored in the AspNetUsers table. As I only have one user in this table, I have no idea where this other GUID is coming from?

I thought that the Id field value from the AspNetUsers table would be returned for the currently logged in user when you call User.Identity.GetUserId()?

I am definitely checking the same database/environment and looking at the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

Thanks to this blog post (see point #2):
https://digitaltoolfactory.net/blog/2013/10/five-things-should-should-know-about-the-new-asp-net-identity-membership-system/

The new MVC5 membership stuff had automatically created a new local database on my laptop called "DefaultConnection" where it had generated and placed all the membership tables and data. So GetUserId() was returning a GUID that lived locally in the AspNetUsers table from that local database which did not exist in my other main database that the application was using! Gah.

So the fix was changing this line inside of IdentityModels.cs:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
```

to:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MyConnectionString") { }
```

Now it works and everything is saved centrally into my application's main database.

Comment: gotta love em:) I am trying to call User.Identity.GetUserId() now after converting to the new AspNet.Identity and it returns null :(

Comment: My problems is reference to wrong usermanager object in ConfigureAuth (startup.auth.cs file). You give me a glue to solve my problem. thank

Comment: It's rather interesting how User.Identity.GetUserId() gave you the actual GUI user ID as opposed to the userName. It's weird I know (and a bit stupid) that the userName should be returned instead of the GUI UserID with that call - but that's just how it is. Now then, explain your sorcery as to how you did that